# "Unsanded Grout" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

I read about **unsanded grout** in a DIY blog and want to buy it. But I don't know how to translate that to spanish. What is it called in Spanish or Castellano?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know in Mexico, "grout" is called "yeso". I have heard that in some countries, don't ask me which ones, it is also called "lechada".

About the "unsanded" part, honestly I have no idea what that means. At best I can only infer that since sand means "arena" maybe, big emphasis on the maybe, it means that the mixture of "yeso" or "lechada" should not contain sand.

I have looked for "[yeso](http://dle.rae.es/yeso)" and "[lechada](http://dle.rae.es/lechada)" in RAE and also for "[yeso](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeso)" in wikipedia but I was not lucky in trying to get more information for you.

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2439219 — “Unsanded” means literally “without sand”. It is used for several things, such as crystal tiles — without sand, it won’t hurt/leave marks in the crystal.”

Comment: The shop owner did know what we mean by using the word  `lechada`.

Comment: @juergend: Maybe now days it is much more common to use "yeso" instead. I'm glad that I was able to help.

Comment: I just want to mention that, in Spain, `lechada` can be misunderstood and, instead of `grout`, people can think about `semen`. It's very, very vulgar, but, frankly, it's the first that came up to my mind. To keep it in mind, just in case.

Comment: Word of warning: You are probably going to run into problems with folks who don't know the difference between mortar, grout and caulk.

Answer (score 5):

Mi esposa es de Perú y ella me dijo la palabra para rellenar grietas es 'masilla'.

I looked up 'masilla' and the translators online refer to it as 'putty', but it may be a regional word.  She added that 'yeso' is used to refer to the material that is used for a cast on a broken bone.

Answer (score 1):

En México se le conoce como "boquilla" es el pega azulejo pero tiene que ser sin arena, (non sander)
Muy tarde mi respuesta, perdón! Espero aún te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for that too and what I found was this: "Adhesivo para pegar azulejo mosaico" o "pega-azulejo".

Answer (score 0):

Sand as a verb is translated as "lijar" in Spanish, so it must be something like "yeso grumoso" or a kind of grout (*yeso*) with a rough finish to it (?).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it isn't "yeso", but it could be Pegacort, which is the "adhesivo para azulejos" and it should be without sand "sin arena", because Pegacort comes with or without sand. "Pegacort sin arena".

Comment: 'Pegacort' is a comercial brand, not the name of a material.

Answer (score 0):

In Mexico the thing that people use for tiles is Pegazulejo, tile is "azulejo" so a raw translation of pegazulejo is "glue-tiles", "the thing that stick tiles" and it needs no sand.